# QML. How to stretch Grid for all parent space

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a custom button:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: xobutton
    width: 100
    height: 100
    property string label: "?"
    border.width: 2

    Text {
        id: xobuttonLabel
        text: label
        font.pointSize: 75
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    } 
}
```

It has a parent `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 500
    height: 500

    Grid {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        rows: 3; columns: 3; spacing: 0

        Repeater {
            model: 9
            Xobtn { }
        }
    } 
}
```

I need to stretch all buttons in `Grid` for all free space in parent `Rectangle`. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Grid` just positions the items in it, respecting the items' size. To have the items actively resized, you need to use [`GridLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-gridlayout.html), and tell it how the items should be resized with [`Layout` attached properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html). So your code becomes something like this, comments showing changes to your code:

```
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1 // needed for GridLayout

Rectangle {
    width: 500
    height: 500

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent // GridLayout must have the right size now
        rows: 3; columns: 3
        columnSpacing: 0; rowSpacing: 0 // changed from spacing: 0

        Repeater {
            model: 9
            Xobtn {
                // attached properties guiding resizing
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you for some reason don't want to depend on `QtQuick.Layouts`, then you have to calculate the `width` and `height` yourself, but this is rather clunky if you need anything but uniform grid, something like:

```
        Xobtn {
            height: grid.parent.height / grid.columns - grid.spacing
            width: grid.parent.width / grid.rows - grid.spacing
        }
```

where `grid` would be the id of the *Grid*.

Answer (score -1):

Without using the QtQuick.Layouts that are a little more expensive, you can just do something like this (but you need to know the size of the items you put in the grid:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 500
    height: 500

    readonly property int rectSize: 100

    Grid {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        rows: 3; columns: 3;

        columnSpacing: (parent.width - (root.rectSize * columns)) / (columns - 1)
        rowSpacing: (parent.height - (root.rectSize * rows)) / (rows - 1)

        Repeater {
            model: parent.rows * parent.columns

            Rectangle {
                id: xobutton
                width: root.rectSize
                height: root.rectSize
                property string label: "?"
                border.width: 2

                Text {
                    id: xobuttonLabel
                    text: label
                    font.pointSize: 75
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```